# Java - no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, ssl, server

Im creating a SSLserver and im trying to send data to it ,but when I create it ,it gives the following error : `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common`

and here is my full code :

```
    Logger.ready("log.txt");
    Logger.log("Logger is now ready!");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "MyKeytool.keytool");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "MyPassword");
    Logger.log("Properties are set!");
    try {
        SSLServerSocket server = (SSLServerSocket) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(9999);
        server.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"});
        Logger.log("Sever was created & is read to connect!");
        while (true) {
            new ServerThread(server.accept()).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and client sided it gives the following error :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

So my Questions are :

Q1: Is this the complete wrong way to go? If it is how shoudl I do it?

Q2: Im currently storing my keytool (Client sided, keytool is the keytool file generated by the java keygen) not save (in the same directory as the aot-compiled jar), but is this save or can Crackers do anything with this keytool like reading something from the connection or similar?

Q3: How should I solve my Problem (make a correct connection), so that I can send data?

Comment: I don't understand your second two questions. Maybe get a better English speaker to proof-read it for you? Really a SO post should only ask one question.

Comment: @slim, mmhhh you were write, corrected it. Is it ok now?

Comment: When you say "key tool" you mean the key file generated by keytool, right?

Comment: Yes your right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that your code is getting a far as connecting with an SSL server, and attempting an SSL handshake.

One of the first things that happens in an SSL handshake, is that the two sides try to agree on a mutually acceptable *cipher suite*. A cipher suite is a named combination of authentication, encryption, message authentication and key exchange algorithms.

Typically the server has a list of cipher suites it understands and considers acceptably secure, and the client has another list.

For example, an OpenSSL server configured to only support TLS1 and above, might have this cipher suite list:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
```

... etc. (there are 80 in total on my system)

The client tells the server which ones it supports. The server picks one that's on its list of supported cipher suites, and responds telling the client which one to use.

You have chosen to configure your client with a list of only one cipher suite. It seems that the server does not support `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` and therefore the server has responded with a handshake failure, including a useful message: `no cipher suites in common`.

It's not a good idea to specify just one cipher suite, because the fewer you allow, the less likely it is that it'll be in the server's list.

Unless you have a good reason to specify cipher suites, you should probably leave your client to use the default list.

`getSupportedCipherSuites()` will provide you all the cipher suites Java can support -- don't enable all of these, as many are disabled by default for good reason.

`getEnabledCipherSuites()`, called before you set any, will give you the defaults. If the defaults aren't fit for your needs, you could start with these defaults and add/remove as necessary.

---

The file containing your private key is as safe as any other file -- it won't get leaked via the `SSLServerSocket`. You should think about other ways it might get read -- make sure it's read-protected, and so on. Consider making it encrypted, and then think about how to protect the password. There's a balance to be chosen here between convenience, cost and security. Some systems require a human to type in the keyfile password every time the system starts. Other systems accept the risk, and have a password file or an unencrypted keyfile (trusting OS file permissions, physical and network security).